# Android debug google in app billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm developping an application in android. The application is already available on the play store.

Anyway, I want to debug the in app billing process I just developped.
If I have well understood, the only way is to publish the apk for alpha/beta testing ? As it takes severals hours to be available, is there an other way to do it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Previously, you could test an app by uploading an unpublished draft version. This functionality is no longer supported; instead, you must publish it to the alpha or beta distribution channel.
Unless the app is available on Google Play [Alpha/Beta/Prduction] you can not do a purchase. Thus you can not debug the billing process.